# Why is (deleted) copy constructor preferred over implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, constructor-overloading

Consider the code below:

```
struct Bar{};

struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Bar&) {}
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;

    // IMPLICIT conversion to Bar
    operator Bar(){return {};}
};

int main() 
{
    Foo f1;
    Foo f2(static_cast<Bar>(f1)); // this is OK
    Foo f3(f1); // does not compile, why not implicit conversion to `Bar`?
}
```

The class `Bar` has a user-defined conversion operator to `Foo`, which accepts `Bar&`s. However, in the last line of `main`, I would have expected `Foo f1` to be converted to a `Bar` then passed to `Foo(const Bar&)`. However, only the deleted constructor `Foo(const Foo&) = delete;` is considered. I understand that this constructor is a better match, but why isn't the `Foo(const Bar&)` also in the overload set and why doesn't the compiler perform an implicit conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is preferred because lookup and overload resolution occurs before the deleted definition is noted on a deleted member function.

That is, the overload resolution will not take into account the `delete` specifier and in your call:

```
Foo f3(f1);
```

Due to the fact that `f1` is of type `Foo`, `Foo(const Foo&)` is a direct parameter type match. Consequently, is of higher rank in overload resolution than `Foo(const Bar&)`.

Comment: Yes, but if you have 2 equally good candidates, and one is `delete`d, I would have expected the compiler to choose the other one. Any reason why this doesn't happen?

Comment: @vsoftco `delete` is more like saying  "call on this will fail"  it doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: I was expected to have a behaviour similar to SFINAE, where the non-matching function is simply ignored if there is another match.

Comment: @vsoftco It seems like you're trying to use deleted functions in a way that differs quite fundamentally from how C++ defines them. What you're after makes perfect sense, it's just not how C++ works. Given e.g. `void f(long); void f(int) = delete;`, `f(1)` won't work, and the `void f(int) = delete;` may well be added *specifically* to make `f(1)` not work. There are such deleted overloads in the standard library. By the rules you would want, `f(1)` would work, it would simply pick the `void f(long)` overload.

Comment: @T.C. Ahh ok, this makes sense, so the deleted one has a higher rank. Thanks.

Comment: That's crystal clear, thanks. Is there any way of removing a function from the overload candidate set? (that's what I first though `=delete` does)

Comment: @vsoftco No there's no way to do this. My suggestion is to stick to the `static_cast` this way you also show your intentions to someone who reads the code.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I bumped into those issues when writing a class for matrix views (lazy evaluation), where I wanted to disable temporaries etc. But I guess I have to think about a change of design ;)

Comment: @M.M Yes but in that case it will bind to the default copy constructor.

Comment: @M.M Won't in this case the compiler define an implicit copy constructor for you?

Comment: @101010 yes, I momentarily thought it was suppressed for some reason

Comment: @M.M I'm curios what happens if I delete the move ctor, which will disable the compiler generated copy ctor...

Comment: @vsoftco If you delete the move ctor copy ctor is implicitly declared deleted as well.

Comment: I'd suggest that what you want is impossible for a good reason:  initializing a `T` from an object of type `T` should always be a copy-construction.  You could of course write `Foo(const Foo&f): Foo(static_cast<Bar>(f)) {}`

Comment: @101010 Yes, it's exactly the same effect as an explicit `=delete`.

Comment: @vsoftco according to cppreference there is no way to suppress all copy-constructors

Comment: @M.M Yes I agree, that's why I should change the design.

Comment: @M.M What do you mean? deleting the move constructor deletes the copy ctor as well.

Comment: @vsoftco then it's defined as deleted (as opposed to not being defined at all), which makes a difference for overload resolution